# Custom the style of each element in a loop [symfony2]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm rendering a list of categories from my database in my index page, i don't know how to give a unique style to each category, it's easy to give a unique style for all the categories, but how to personalize the style to each one.

Each category is render in a grid block and each grid block have his own style.

What happening right now is each category are repeated by the number of category in the database.

**This is my twig file:**

```
{% for entity in entities %}
            <div class="global-wrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row row-wrap">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                                    <div class="thumb">
                                        <a class="hover-img" href="{{ path('categorieProducts', { 'entity' : entity.id }) }}">
                                            <img height="357px" width="100%" src="{{  asset('bundles/flyplatform/img/blog1.jpg')}}" alt="Image Alternative text" title="" />
                                            <div class="hover-inner hover-inner-block hover-inner-bottom hover-inner-bg-black hover-hold">
                                                <div class="text-small">
                                                    <h5 style="font-family: Lato, sans-serif; text-align: center;font-size: 34px;font-weight: 500">{{ entity.name }}</h5>
                                                    <h6 style="text-align: right;font-family: Lato, sans-serif;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 400">77497 reviews</h6>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                                    <div class="thumb">
                                        <a class="hover-img" href="{{ path('categorieProducts', { 'entity' : entity.id }) }}">
                                            <img height="357px" width="100%" src="{{  asset('bundles/flyplatform/img/blog1.jpg')}}"  alt="Image Alternative text" title="" />
                                            <div class="hover-inner hover-inner-block hover-inner-bottom hover-inner-bg-black hover-hold">
                                                <div class="text-small">
                                                    <h5>{{ entity.name }}</h5>
                                                    <h6>54531 reviews</h6>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                                    <div class="thumb">
                                        <a class="hover-img" href="{{ path('categorieProducts', { 'entity' : entity.id }) }}">
                                            <img height="357px" width="100%" src="{{  asset('bundles/flyplatform/img/blog1.jpg')}}" alt="Image Alternative text" title="" />
                                            <div class="hover-inner hover-inner-block hover-inner-bottom hover-inner-bg-black hover-hold">
                                                <div class="text-small">
                                                    <h5>{{ entity.name }}</h5>
                                                    <h6>68703 reviews</h6>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                                    <div class="thumb">
                                        <a class="hover-img" href="{{ path('categorieProducts', { 'entity' : entity.id }) }}">
                                            <img height="357px" width="100%" src="{{  asset('bundles/flyplatform/img/grid1.png')}}" alt="Image Alternative text" title="" />
                                            <div class="hover-inner hover-inner-block hover-inner-bottom hover-inner-bg-black hover-hold">
                                                <div class="text-small">
                                                    <h5 style="font-family: Lato, sans-serif; text-align: center;font-size: 34px;font-weight: 500">{{ entity.name }}</h5>
                                                    <p style="text-align: right;font-family: Lato, sans-serif;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 400">44391 reviews</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
{% endfor %}
```

.

```
 public function categorycityAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Categories')->findAll();
        return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:categorycity.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities));
    }
```

**ADD:**

the answer of @zizoujab  give me the idea to render each category separately in the page index and each category have his own controller action then for each controller action i can make a query builder that will search the category id the database.

but i have the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Controller
>   "FLY\xxxxxxxBundle\Controller\PostController::categorylondonAction()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$entity" argument (because
>   there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument
>   after this one).")

**index.html.twig**

```
 {% render (controller('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:categorylondon')) %}
```

**PostRepository.php**

london category have the `id 1` in the database.

```
public function byLondon($entity)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')
        ->Where('u.id = 1')
        ->orderBy('u.id')
        ->setParameter('entity', $entity);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

.

**PostController.php**

```
public function categorylondonAction($entity)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Categories')->byLondon($entity);
    return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:categorylondon.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed my issue.

This is how i render my controller in index.html.twig:

```
{% render (controller('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:categorylondon' , { 'id': 1 })) %}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function categorylondonAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Categories')->findBy(array('id' => $id));
        return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:categorylondon.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities));
    }
```

Thank you @VaN and @zizoujab for you help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all for readabilty reasons , you may write template of a single category ( all that html code in the for loop ) in a separate `.html.twig` file , let's call it `category_item.html.twig`.

your code will now look like this :

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    {% include 'path_to_category_item.html.twig' %}
{% endfor %}
```

for the unique style I cant think of a way that can give you a custom style for each category  specially if the categories count is dynamic.

So either you give a random values for styles or you store the style with each category. Like that you will be passing the style for each category like this :

```
{% for entity in entities %}
      {% include 'path_to_category_item.html.twig' with {'style': entity.style} %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sorry for the late response.Your answer give me the idea to render each category separately in the page index and each category have his own controller action then for each controller action i can make a query builder that will search the category `id` the database. I tried with what i explained to you right now and it seems working, but i have the following error: `categorylondonAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$entity" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).")` , i added the new code on top.

Comment: `categorylondonAction()` has an `$entity` argument which is missing when you called `render` twig function. try this  `{% render (controller('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:categorylondon'  , { 'entity': 1 })))) %}`

Comment: i tried with your example but i have this error: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Undefined method 'byLondon'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!")`. i added my controller in my post on top.

Comment: Symfony2 doesn't seem to recognize your repository method `byLondon` could you check that you are mentioning  in the Post Entity that is has a repository Called PostRepository ?

Comment: my Post Entity called the PostRepository ->  `* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\PostRepository")`, i have other query builder in the post repository and it work, i don't understand why with byLondon it doesn't work.

Comment: becaues in your post controller you are calling Categories Repository not Post Repository. 
`$entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Categories <- change this ')->byLondon($entity);`

Comment: i changed this ligne  `$entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Categories')->byLondon($entity);`   by `$entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->byLondon($entity);` my table Post is link to the table Categories (ManyToOne), that means i have also to change my query builder in the PostReposity ? after changing `FLYBookingsBundle:Categories` to  `FLYBookingsBundle:Post` i got this error : `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Undefined method 'byLondon'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122193/discussion-between-zizoujab-and-sirius).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new property in Category entity, to store a css class.
then, use this property in your loop, and configure these css class in your css file.

Entity :

```
class Category
{
    private $cssClass;
}
```

View :

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    [...]
    <div class="category-container {{entity.cssClass }}">
        [...]
    </div>
    [...]
{% endfor %}
```

CSS file :

```
.category-container {
    // here the global css properties common to all the categories
}
.category-01 {
    // here the css properties unique to this category
    [...]
}
```